# Changing the source Repository herkou

Tags: git, heroku, bitbucket

I have a Heroku instance running from a specified source repository. This source repository was on my personal BitBucket account (Let's call it old_repo). 
I would like to move the source repository to a newly created BitBucket Account (new_repo) without having to create a new Heroku instance.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just change the remote of your repository?
https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/  
Also you could look into the Codeship plugin Heroku is providing, there you can configure on which repository the plugin is "listening" for changes and it will be build and deployed to your Heroku app.